# What the half close does in http2? What the diff between local and remote in stream state in http2?

Tags: http, https, netty, http2

What the half close does in http2? What the diff between local and remote in stream state in http2?

I have seen that: `reserved(local) --> half closed(remote)` in the lifecycle of a stream.

Why local to remote? why not `reserved(local) --> half closed(local)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each stream will have two different view points - the client and the server, the requester and the provider. Call it what you want.

So the "reserved" state is used when a PUSH_PROMISE has been sent. At this point the server has stated it intends to push a resource on another stream, so that stream identifier is reserved and cannot be used for anything but this pushed resource.

At this point the server sees it as follows:

- It will be a server-initiated stream so will be an even numbered stream.
- The server has reserved the stream id itself - it was not reserved by the remote client. Hence `reserved (local)`
- It will then send the HEADERS frame response. At this point the server has started sending the resource so when this happens HTTP/2 basically says the stream is closed from the client point of view - it's to listen to incoming data, but not to send any data (other than control signals like WINDOWS_UPDATE, PRIORITY or RST_STREAM frames). The stream is effectively now one-way or *half-closed* and it is closed to the remote client sending any data, but the local server is still allowed to send data - hence `half closed (remote)`

The client will see the **exact same flow** from the opposite point of view:

- It knows from the PUSH_PROMISE that a stream has been reserved and it should expect it to come in soon.
- As the stream is a server-initiated stream it's not one the client created so it's treated as a remotely reserved stream - hence `reserved (remote)`
- After the server starts sending the data, the client knows it's not allowed to send any data on that stream (not that it really was for Push Promise streams but still). It can re-prioritize the pushed resource (using a PRIORITY frame) or even cancel it (using RST_STREAM frame) but that's all it can do (other than acknowledge receipt of data using the WINDOWS_UPDATE frame). The stream is therefore restricted as to what the client can send on it - or as the spec prefers to say it is *half-closed* for any client (aka local) requests - hence `half-closed (local)`.

The key to understanding the [HTTP/2 state model](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#StreamStates) is to realise that a request does not flow down one side or the other - but down both sides at the same time! It just depends whether you are looking at it from the sender or receiver point of view.

Comment: Your explanations are so good!! Thank you so much!!
I have one more question, why PUSH_PROMISE is only a header?
In the rfc, `PUSH_PROMISE frame (with implied CONTINUATIONs)`, which means by sending PUSH_PROMISE , the data/content should be sent as well?
But seems data/content is sent by sending Header rather than PP?

Comment: Why thank you for the compliment! Check out my book if you like the style of my answers and want to learn more about HTTP/2 than can fit in a SO question: https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action?a_aid=tunetheweb&a_bid=a810f9b6

Comment: Definitely will check out your book!

Comment: A PUSH_PROMISE is not the pushed resource. It is a dummy request that is meant to act like an incoming HEADERS request for that resource would have looked like if it had come in as normal instead of being pushed by the server. So normal request is: HEADERS (sent), HEADERS (received), DATA (received). A pushed resource is: PUSH_PROMISE (received), HEADERS (received), DATA (received). And as only GET requests can be pushed there is no body with the PUSH_PROMISE. The PUSH_PROMISE Frame is needed to warn the client there is about to be an incoming request and what stream id that will be on.

Comment: Also the PUSH_PROMISE Frame is sent on the stream for the original requests that caused the push to happen (e.g. Stream id: 1) and includes a promised stream id. The actually Pushed resource (HEADERS and DATA) happens on the promise stream (e.g. Stream id: 2).

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much for the details!